# Is there a way to add dynamic headers like Authorisation before running sampler?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, hmac

I am setting up Jmeter for permformance testing. However, my API requires HMAC authentication before hitting the API. I have the JS script for the same.

```
vars.put('hmacAuthHeader', response);
```

And in the Header Manager, I have added a header as:

```
Authorization: ${hmacAuthHeader}
```

After running the sampler, when I check the request headers it is still the same. Also, the hmac generation logic depends on the request I am sending to the server something like this:

```
if(request['method'] == 'GET') {
    l_content_type  =   '';
}
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the java code for it .
  // If username password is there than
          `AuthManager manager = new AuthManager();
            Authorization authorization = new Authorization();
            //  authorization.setURL("http://url");
            authorization.setUser("username");
            authorization.setPass("password");
            manager.addAuth(authorization);
            manager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("auth_manager_title")); // $NON-NLS-1$
            manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, AuthManager.class.getName());
            manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, AuthPanel.class.getName());`